# Do I need a sleep on receiving data from socket Python

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I'm new to sockets. I've written a simple 'proxy' server in Python that will just catch the data from the remote server and send it to my client (browser). I was wondering: is there a way to send the response_text without a time.sleep? While i try to delete `time.sleep(0.5)` I only get one package of data from the remote server so the 'Content-lenght' isn't equal to the length of the package and I get an error (I'm using recv() to get a buffer with size equaled to buffer_size, so if the server data needs more then one package of 4096 bytes I need to catch it in the next package). With the time.sleep i get all the packages of data from the remote server and I can send the data to my browser. Am I doing something wrong? Or I just don't know enough? Can someone help?

The code:

```
# coding: utf-8
import socket
import sys
import time
from thread import *

max_conn = 5
buffer_size = 4096


def proxy_server(webserver, port, conn, addr, data):
    try:
        remote_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        remote_sock.connect((webserver, port))
        remote_sock.send(data)
        response_text = ''
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            response = remote_sock.recv(buffer_size)
            response_text += response
            if len(response) < buffer_size:
                remote_sock.close()
                break
        conn.sendall(response_text)
        conn.close()
    except socket.error, msg:
        print 'Proccessing error. Error Code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ', Wiadomość: ' + msg[1]
        remote_sock.close()
        conn.close()
        sys.exit()


def conn_string(conn, data, address):
    header = data.split('\r\n')
    method, address, protocol = header[0].split(' ')
    host_key, host_value = header[1].split(': ')
    proxy_server(host_value, 80, conn, address, data)


def start():
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.bind(('', 8001))
        sock.listen(max_conn)
        print 'Proxy: on'
    except socket.error, msg:
        print 'Failed creating a socket. Error Code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ', Wiadomość: ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit()

    while True:
        try:
            connection, address = sock.accept()
            data = connection.recv(buffer_size)
            # start_new_thread(conn_string, (connection, data, address))
            conn_string(connection, data, address)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sock.close()
            print "Socket closed"
            sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

Comment: If you have a content-length header then use the value of the attribute to loop over socket recv's until the correct number of bytes have been recv'ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `time.sleep()` , it makes your proxy **very** slow , and its not efficient .
You need to set your socket in non-blocking mode , with a timeout .
You can do this with `socket.settimeout()`
I made a few modifications to your `proxy_server` , it should be much faster now .

```
def proxy_server(webserver, port, conn, addr, data): 
    try:
        remote_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        remote_sock.connect((webserver, port))
        remote_sock.send(data)
        remote_sock.settimeout(0.5)
        response_text = ''
        while True:
            try : 
                response = remote_sock.recv(buffer_size)
                if len(response) == 0:
                    break
            except : 
                break
            response_text += response
        conn.sendall(response_text)
    except socket.error, msg:
        if str(msg) != 'timed out' : 
            print 'Proccessing error. Error Code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ', Wiadomość: ' + msg[1]
    remote_sock.close()
    conn.close()
```

The rest of your code is quite ok , but you may want to use multithreading
if you want to handle multiple clients at the same time .

Comment: With non-blocking sockets you do not need to use multithreading, you can instead use select() or poll() to find out which sockets need to be read from or written to, and handle them all with a single thread.  That has the advantage of avoiding all the standard multithreading gotchas (race conditions, deadlocks, mutexes, etc)

Comment: Yes , you are right about that , assuming that the server's timeout is very low , or that there are only a few clients

Comment: In my experience timeouts are never necessary with TCP-based servers (unless you server is actually doing something explicitly time-related, of course).  Rather, everything can be (and for best performance, should be) purely event-driven.

Comment: If you run `sock.accept()` in an infinite loop , with a non-blocking socket and 0 timeout , very soon you ll get 100% GPU usage .  The OP would have to change completely his `start()` function ( you could post an answer to that )

Comment: You would indeed -- if your event loop didn't include a call to select() or poll().  In a proper event-driven non-blocking-sockets design, the select() (or poll()) call is the only place in the code where you ever block, and you block there until a socket becomes ready to be handled (e.g. until it has a TCP connection to accept(), or data to recv(), or buffer space available to send() (only if you want to send() data, of course)).  Then you handle whatever needs handling, then go back to blocking inside select()/poll() again, and repeat ad infinitum.

Comment: I see what you mean , thanks for explaining in detail

Comment: Hi there, first of all thanks guys for answering my question :) Indeed the proxy works very slow (I was Aware that it would end this way) and I would want to speed it up. @t.m.adam I tried using the ``settimeout(0.5)`` but while i connect to for example stackoverflow.com i get timed out all the time, I tried modifying the timeout value to 0.75 but still I get timed out. I don't think that setting it to a bigger value would help, it would rather end up like my first version of the proxy with ``time.sleep``. But when I debug it with ``ipdb`` then it works like a charm. How can I get it working?

Comment: I updated the code to catch timeouts in `recv()` , it should be ok now .  If it still doent work try with 2 - 3 sec timeout or with `select()` as @Jeremy Friesner suggested .

Comment: Yes it works now :) I still have to handle the case that in my ``start()`` the connection gets empty data (``data='' ``). But thats not related with the question i think :) thanks!!

Comment: I m glad i could help . Why dont you just close the `conn` and `return` in case `len(data) == 0`  in `conn_string` ?

Comment: Ou yes! I forgot to close the connection in the ``conn_string`` in the ``len(data) == 0`` case. I was thinking why my proxy was hanging.. Thanks again for the help